# Backbone Jaydata Odata

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, odata, jaydata

I have an [OData(v3)](http://www.odata.org/) endpoint that will be used with a mobile [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) application.

I am trying to integrate [Jaydata](http://jaydata.org/) to avoid building the OData queries.

I am still developing my Backbone skills and I am not sure how to integrate Jaydata with my Models/Collections.

My first assumption is that I need to override the `sync` method but I am not sure this is the way to go.

Any suggestions or examples would be great.

If you have an alternative to Jaydata for my problem that would also be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just as an interims solution till JayData's Backbone adapter is ready ;-). For an example that connects Backbone to an OData v2 provider (SharePoint) check out https://github.com/lstak/Backbone.SharePoint/blob/master/backbone-sharepoint.odata.js. This shows you how to leverage Backbone's `sync` method to accomplish CRUD operations. No fancy OData function support of course.

Answer (score 2):

We do plan to support backbone in the nearest future. I think that you can have a pre-release version within a few weeks maybe sooner.
Cheers
Gabor

Comment: That sounds great. Unfortunately I will have to find something till then. Looking forward to it tough ...

Comment: if you do not insist on using backbone, you can use jaydata itself or we support jquery, handlebars, kendo ui, extjs, knockoutjs

Comment: Hi it is still on the drawing board but we are busy with some more frequently requested features. Please be patient.

Comment: Are we there yet? Jaydata for backbone?